# Using c# generics in a nested class

Tags: c#, generics, nested-class

Consider the following class structure:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
    }

    public class Bar<U> where U : Foo<T>, new()
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            var blah = new U();
            blah.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}

public class Baz
{
}

public class FooBaz : Foo<Baz>
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

When I go to use the nested class, I have something like the following:

```
var x = new FooBaz.Bar<FooBaz>();
```

It seems redundant to have to specify it twice.  How would I create my class structure such that I can do this instead:

```
var x = new FooBaz.Bar();
```

Shouldn't there be some way on the where clause of the nested class to say that U is always the parent?  How?

---

Update: Added methods for DoSomething() above to address some of the comments.  It's important that when I call DoSomething, it addresses the overridden version.  If I just use Foo instead of U, then the base implementation is called instead.

Comment: How do you use `U` inside `Bar`? Wouldn't using `Foo<T>` instead suffice?

Comment: IMO Best thing you can do is what you doing now.

Comment: Foo<T> does not suffice because I may have overridden methods in FooBaz.  If Bar just refers to Foo<T>, it uses the base implementation in Foo<T>.

Comment: If you have overridden methods, that means you also have an instance of `Foo<T>` and that means using `Foo<T>` as the type should work. If `FooBaz` overrides some methods, those are the ones that will be called. That's how virtual methods work.

Comment: If you say "new Foo<T>()", you do not automatically get a FooBaz just because one is defined.  I'll update the question with some methods so you can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `class Bar` does not need to be generic, why do you make it one?

This would work:

```
public class Foo<T, U> where U : Foo<T, U>
{     
    public class Bar
    {
        private T t;
        private U u;
    }
}

public class Baz
{
}

public class FooBaz : Foo<Baz, FooBaz>
{
}
```

And then

```
var bar = new FooBaz.Bar();
```

Of course all of this is totally abstract, so it might or might not apply to a practical example. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: When `U` is not useful in container class why pass it as generic parameter?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Because it *may* be useful (I added fields of types `T` and `U` to hint towards this). How do you know that it's not?

Comment: Ok, this *might* work, but I'm not sure about the recursion going on in the definition of FooBaz.  I'll try it out.

Comment: Ok, this does indeed work.  But it's just a tradeoff of moving the redundant type specification to the parent class instead of the child.  I have many more of Foo than Bar, so I guess I will leave it as I originally showed.  Basically, this solution asks the same question, but of SELF rather than PARENT.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jon, if it is useful OP should add them in container class not you. we just can judge about what we can see

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't merge that.

Inside Foo you have T *and* U, 2 different types and the compiler cannot make up a type for U, only constrain it.

Comment: This is where I wish StackOverflow could let me pick two accepted answers.  This is indeed true.  Jon's answer has a bit more detail though.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you introduce U at all? Can you not replace its use everywhere within the definition of `Bar` with `Foo<T>`?

Comment: Again, no.  Using Foo<T> does not suffice because I may have overridden methods in FooBaz. If Bar just refers to Foo<T>, it uses the base implementation in Foo<T>.

Comment: Ok, this was not clear to me from the initial question. Hence I asked why you introduced U.